# Why does Luv say they're going "home"?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

Sorry, this is all spoiler

> When they're taking Deckard off-world for torture, and he asks where they're going, Luv says "home". Does she mean home for her? Or home for him? Is this a give-away about him being a replicant from the old days?

Comment: I think it was a reference to replicants' original purpose as an off-world hard labour force. But it could also have been a more emotional "we don't belong with humans" type sentiment.

Comment: Knowing Blade Runner, it's probably intentionally ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You've hit the ambiguous nail right on the head (or did you perhaps miss?). Denis Villeneuve didn't want to be the one to give the game away about Deckard being human or replicant, stating that *"[I enjoyed the ambiguity and I did not want to ruin the mystery for fans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/171553/20774)"*.

LUV certainly means *her* home (Niander confirmed in the scene before that he's taking Deckard to an offworld Colony with a Wallace facility, probably the one that she was decanted from), but she might also mean *their* shared home, assuming she knows something that we don't.

> NIANDER WALLACE: Offworld I have everything I need to make you talk. You don’t know what pain is yet. You will learn.
>
> Luv grins -- dark work she will enjoy, and --

[later]

> **DECKARD:** *Where are we going?*
>
> **LUV:** ***Home.***
>
> **Deckard’s gaze drifts up**... to watch the rain and snow stream
> across the glass...